# image slide gallery with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm try to create a sliding banner with jquery here.

I tried to code in this manner

```
    .post(this,{ajax : 1}, function(data){
    var oldImage = $('div.banner > img');
    var newImage = $(data).insertAfter(oldImage).css('position','absolute').css('left',800);
    newImage.load(function(){ 
oldImage.animate({left:-800},'medium',function(){});    newImage.animate({left:0},'medium',function(){
oldImage.remove();
    });
});
});
return false;
```

However, the transition between the 2 images is not smooth, and there seem to have
a little gap between the 2 image when the old image slide away, and the new image 
slide in. I assume is because there is a lag between the execution of image. 
Do you guys have any tips on how I can better do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have should work alright.  The *perceived* lag is probably the image not actually being 800px wide.  Since you're animating 800px left and 800px right for the new/old image, if they aren't actually that wide, there'll be a gap in there.

You can either use the [`slide` effect](http://jqueryui.com/demos/show/) for this, or adjust the `left` amounts to be the correct size for the images, e.g. via [`.width()`](http://api.jquery.com/width/).

For the gap "lag" and the width, [you can see what I mean here](http://jsfiddle.net/Ajm7S/).  There's a large gap, but only because the `left` property of 800px is larger than the 275px image in the example.